# babel-cli transform only files with specific extension

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Currently I'm using babel to transpile my JSX wiews via `npm run script`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "npm run transpile-views",
    "start": "node ./src",
    "transpile-views": "babel ./src/views --out-dir ./src/views",
    "lint": "eslint src",
  }
}
```

I'm using the same directory (src/views) as input and output directory transpiling `.jsx` files to `.js`. But when there's already transpiled files in the directory and run again `npm run transpile-views` babel take all `.jsx` and `.js` files.

```
> my-project@1.0.0 transpile-views ~/Projects/my-project
> babel ./src/views --out-dir ./src/views

srcviews/AuthView.js -> src/views/AuthView.js
src/views/AuthView.jsx -> src/views/AuthView.js
src/views/HomeView.js -> src/views/HomeView.js
src/views/HomeView.jsx -> src/views/HomeView.js
src/views/MainLayout.js -> src/views/MainLayout.js
src/views/MainLayout.jsx -> src/views/MainLayout.js
```

Is there a way to specify the extension of input files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Babel has option -x or --extensions, you can specify:

```
babel ./src/views -x ".jsx" --out-dir ./src/views
```

https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that, I tried that but the output creates a folder in `./src/views/src/views`

Comment: It doesn't do anything, also tried `"transpile-views": "babel ./src/views  -x '*.jsx' --out-dir ./src/views",`

Comment: It's weird, `node_modules\.bin\babel ./src/views -x ".jsx" --out-dir ./src/views` works good.

Comment: Ok, I figure it out, it have to be `"transpile-views": "babel ./src/views -x \".jsx\" --out-dir ./src/views"` in the `package.json`.

Comment: how to transpile multiple files with different extensions using babel?